# Can Superman Starve To Death?

Tags: dc, superman

We know that Superman does eat "human" food. However, is it really necessary for him to eat, i.e. can he starve to death? If yes, would he take the same time to die as an average human?

Also the same question goes for water.

Comment: As Superman is solar-powered, I don't think so. But, there're many canon versions of him in existence. So, in the end, it all depends on writers...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Sachin Shekhar stated it all depends on the writer in question, but generally Superman enjoys food and drink but he doesn't have to eat in order to survive.
So, he's kind of like a plant, he absorbs solar energy to sustain his body.
You can read about his solar power ability [here](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_%28Clark_Kent%29)
From the DC Wiki

> Self-Sufficiency: Doesn't need to eat and sleep so long as he's under the effects of yellow sun radiation. His body stores the energy necessary to negate eating and sleeping for an indefinite period.

His weaknesses are Psionics, Magic, Kryptonite, other Kryptonians, Doomsday (and other villains), a Red Sun, a lack of radiation from a yellow sun, and he can't see through lead.

Comment: Yet in the exceptionally well-researched 'Death and Life of Superman' novel, Superman explicitly describes his need for sleep.  He comments (in internal monologue) how he got through college extremely fast, due to only needing to sleep for an hour.  He then wryly thinks to himself that, "if [he] doesn't get at least two hours a night now, [he's] wiped the next day."

Comment: @Jeff that's more than likely a psychological need rather than a phsyical one.